# Plop.js AddMany action type creates unnecessary folders

Tags: plop

I have a folder with all my templates in it
While using addMany action it adds my template folder that I don't want

```js
plop.setGenerator(generators.serverless, {
    prompts: {
      type: 'input',
      name: 'name',
      message: 'Choose test file name',
    },
    actions: (data) => [
      {
        type: 'addMany',
        destination: 'src/functions/{{name}}',
        templateFiles: `serverless/templates/${serverlessTempates.endpoint}/**/*`,
      }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add base in your action like this

```js
{
   type: 'addMany',
   destination: 'src/functions/{{name}}',
   base: `serverless/templates/${serverlessTempates.endpoint}/`,
   templateFiles: `serverless/templates/${serverlessTempates.endpoint}/**/*`,
},
```